# Cell Array containing cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have a cell array containing 1x4 cells

```
A=
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
```

What I'm looking for is to make a cell array containing something like the following

```
B={'str1','str2','str3','str4';cell2mat(A{1,1})}
```

A cell array comes from another operations where the size in rows and columns can vary, so I would like to know weather or not this could be automatized using a for loop or something like that.

Edit:
Sorry i would like to have an array `B`:

```
B{m,n}={'str1','str2','str3','str4';cell2mat(A{m,n})}
```

where `m` and `n` are the rows and columns of cell array `A`.

So lets say I have something like

```
A=
[1 2 3 4] [4 5 6 7] 
[8 9 10 11] [11 12 13 14]
```

I would like to obtain an output `B` of the form

```
B{1}=
'str1' 'str2' 'str3' 'str4'
  1        2     3     4
  8        9    10   11
B{2}=
'str1' 'str2' 'str3' 'str4'
  4        5.      6       7
 11      12     13     14
```

Comment: be more specific and give us an example of one of the cells of `A`, and how you expect the corresponding cell in the output `B` to be..

Comment: I'm afraid that is still not clear enough. What is the size of A and then the size of B?

Comment: you need to replace `cell2mat` with `num2cell`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
B = cellfun(@(x) {'str1','str2','str3','str4',cell2mat(x)}, A, 'Uniform',false);
```

or

```
B = cellfun(@(x) ['str1','str2','str3','str4',x], A, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

depending on whether you want to "flatten" the elements or not in each cell. It's hard to tell without knowing what is inside each cell `A{m,n}`.